# Steven Speilberg movie vs Steven Speilsberg’s movie

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> How does it feel to be the lead in a Steven Speilberg movie?

Vs

> How does it feel to be the lead in a Steven Speilberg’s movie?

Which one is correct of the two?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is correct.

The name of the director is being used as an adjective phrase. In this case, it might refer to any movie that Steven Spielberg directs or produces.

The second sentence needs be changed to read either:

> How does it feel to be the lead in Steven Spielberg's movie?

In this instance, you lose the article **a** and the context indicates that the movie has already been identified.

Or:

> How does it feel to be the lead in a movie of Steven Spielberg?

This is an alternative construction to your first sentence and again could refer to any movie in which the director is involved.

Note that he's Steven SPIELBERG and NOT Steven SPEILBERG.